# what does slash double underscore slash mean? /__/

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase

On github i see this path to a file:

```
importScripts('/__/firebase/3.8.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/3.8.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');
```

What does the "/__/" stands for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Firebase Hosting, the Firebase SDK along with a script that initializes the SDK for the current project are automatically served from special reserved URLs. You can read more about it [on this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html).

Answer (score 0):

This means all the libraries are inside root folder.